# Counting Non-Highlighted Cells

Tags: database, excel, vba

Good Morning Community!

I was wondering if someone could possibly help me find a solution to a problem I am having. So I have one sheet in excel that I want to use as a sort of Dashboard for an easy look and the second sheet I have all my data. I want to use some sort of function or formula to get all my data to my dashboard...my problem is being that some of my cells are highlighted and I only want the non-highlighted cells counted.

Let me know if you need anymore info!

Comment: Why are they highlighted?  Is it through conditional formatting, or is the user highlighting them through cell format?

Comment: The user is highlighting them through cell format when they are completed, voided or shipped.

Comment: If it had be conditional formatting then you could simply use the rule by which it was filled to include in your count, but as it is manually done the only way is vba.  Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a place where users can put their wish list and we will churn out some code. Stack Overflow is here to help overcome specific problems with existing code. If you have code that has errors then please [edit] your question to include that code and an explanation of the error(s), so we may help you.

Comment: Completely understood and I will look for the VBA and try it out. Thanks for the help!